# How to deal with User's timezones in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know it's difficult to detect user's timezones so it would be a best practice to display available timezones to the users and let them select.

How do I get this generated for Rails?

Also how would I use this? Should I save this as string "US/Michigan" and use some class methods to convert this in my current server time when I want to process some user related cron tasks?

Comment: What are you trying to solve for here? this question seems really vague.

Answer (score 0):

The TZInfo gem should be helpful to you:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/frames

(On Windows, you also need tzinfo-data to support it, on other OS's you shouldn't).

There are a LOT of timezones, so I'm not sure if displaying a list of all of them is the best UI or not. But you could.

```
TZInfo::Timezone.all
```

Will return all timezones as TZInfo::Timezone objects. (583 objects).  To get the canonical identifiers for each timezone, you could do:

```
TZInfo::Timezone.all.collect(&:canonical_identifier)
```

It looks like some canonical identifiers are of the form "America/New York", but others are not. "Libya", "Egypt", technical things like "Etc/GMT+7" -- so maybe you don't really want to show all of them.   It looks like instead of `TZInfo::Timezone.all`, you could use `ZInfo::Timezone.all_country_zone_identifiers` to get just the more "normal" ones (still 418).

You could also choose to have the user choose a country first, then choose a timezone from within that country -- TZInfo supports that, grouping timezones by country where they are in use, see the README for more info.

I'm not really sure what the best UI here is. If I were you, I'd look at as many websites and apps as possible to see how they do it -- although it might  be hard to find any that let the user choose the timezone!  Figuring out the right UI and implementing it are kind of two separate problems. But once you figure out the UI you want, the TZInfo gem should give you what you need to implement it.

I think you probably *do* want to 'detect' the user's timezone first, and only force them to select it if they notice the detection was wrong. I'm not sure the best ways to try and detect. I havne't used it, but [here's a Javascript library] that tries to detect user's current timezone as the canonical identifier you should be able to use with TZInfo to actually convert to GMT or another timezone.

Timezones are officially uniquely identified by strings like "America/New York", so that is what makes sense to store as representing a timezone, yep. And TZInfo will give you the methods you need to take those canonical identifiers, and use them to get a timezone object you can use to convert from local time in that timezone to GMT or server time. (You are probably best off always using GMT in your code and storing as GMT in the database, rather than 'server local time').